# Python gspread - Requested writing within range, but tried writing to additional row

Tags: python, gspread

Running into an issue with this code which converted an array into a df then updated a google sheet with more recent data that worked about a week ago:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 
'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8'])

gc = gs.service_account(filename=CloudPathCredentials)
ws = gc.open("Spreadsheetname").worksheet("Sheet1")
firsthold = holder[0]
lasthold = holder[-1]
cellmatch1 = ws.find(firsthold)
cellmatch2 = ws.find(lasthold)
begrow = str(cellmatch1.row)
endrow = str(cellmatch2.row)
begrange = "A" + begrow
endrange = "H" + endrow
fullrange = begrange + ":" + endrange
values = df2.values.tolist()
ws.update(fullrange, values)
```

now it is attempting to write to 1 row after the data ends for some reason and throws the error:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Requested writing within range [Sheet1!1757:1890], but tried writing to row [1891]', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

Comment: Could you define what holder, gs and gc are ? And is your spreadsheet name really "Spreadsheetname" ?

Comment: holder is just an empty array I use to find the first and last value of col6, gs is gspread, gc defines the service account, and no it is just a placeholder!

Comment: Does your sheetname contain special characters ? This might be a problem.

Comment: Aside from spaces no special characters in either the sheet name or the worksheet name

Comment: Can you provide the sample values of `fullrange` and `values` for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: Try to remove the space from your sheetname then